# Fastest way to do this concatenation of lists

Tags: python, list

I am looking for the most efficient way to concatenate lists in this fashion:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
b = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Desired result:

```
result = [[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]], [[4,5,6], [4,5,6]]]
```

I could not find an easy one-liner and am quite confused by all the different methods available.

Comment: `result = [a, b]`

Comment: @Avinash The result with that would be `[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]`

Comment: @ChatterOne, ohh sorry I missed

Answer (score 2):

With numpy you can use the `np.stack` command.

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
b = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

result = np.stack((a,b), axis=-2)
```

##### Output

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

And, if the list format is required, you can convert it to list using the `.tolist()` method.

```
np.stack((a,b), axis=-2).tolist()
```

##### Output

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

Comment: That seems overkill to import numpy just for this, this library cost a lot of time to be imported

Comment: You only need to import the stack function if it is a concern for you.

Comment: The issue is not the function, you're adding a dependency on a library that needs to be in the requirements (and maintained), for something that can easily be solved without it

Comment: Many overused modules are dependent from numpy, so I think it is a safe bet to use it as it is well maintained. Then, my method is of course only one way to do it, which is on my opinion beginner friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Try this:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
b = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
result = [list(x) for x in zip(a,b)]

print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

Comment: this is a copy paste of my solution, apart from the exterior shape, isn't it?

Comment: @lemon, where have you used list comprehension in your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using Python [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) built-in functions this way:

```
list(map(list, zip(a,b)))
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

Explanation:

- `zip(a,b)`: pairs up each list between the two variables (outputs `[([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), ([4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6])]`)
- `map(list, zip(...))`: converts every element of the outer list from tuple to list (outputs `[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), ([4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]]`)
- `list(...)`: used for printing purposes

Answer (score 1):

This works and should be quite fast as it is lazily evaluated:

```py
from itertools import chain

a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
b = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

result = chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b))
print(list(result))
# prints: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```

###### Side note

You could also use the [More Itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package which contains lots of performant recipes that augment the standard `itertools` module for handling iterators and collections.

In this scenario you could use [`more_itertools.interleave(a, b)`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave) to achive exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everybody! All methods work great but there is one thing i need that is missing. I should have been more precise, sorry. I also want the code to be flexible in such a way that I can continue to insert arrays in such a fashion that if the next incoming data is:

```
c = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

I can continue inserting it so that the arrays grows like:

```
result = [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

This seems to be a little bit more complex I guess.

Comment: In my answer just modify `zip(a, b)` to `zip(a, b, c)` and you'll get this result.

Comment: Sure but my c is not available yet. How should I say. The single arrays are data coming in. So first a comes in and i want to store it in the buffer so to speak. Then b is coming in (overwriting variable a), and I want to store it in the buffer in this inserting fashion. Then c is coming in, and again I want to store/insert it in my buffer.

Comment: you could simply do it using `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Surely it's as simple as:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
b = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

c = [[a_,b_] for a_, b_ in zip(a, b)]

print(c)
```

**Output:**

[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]]